# Efficiently compute pairwise Jaccard similarity from sparse array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have an array like the following, with each row being an observation and each column being a feature:

```
import scipy
my_sparse_array = scipy.sparse.random(2000, 10000000, density=0.01, format='csr')
```

For each pair of observations (rows), I want to compute the Jaccard similarity between them - considering that a nonzero value in the array means that the feature is present while zero values indicate absence of the feature. Therefore, the intersection would be where both observations have a nonzero value for a feature, while union is where only one of the observations has a nonzero value. Features where both are zero are to be ignored.

What is the most efficient way of doing this pairwise computation. My plan was to make combinations of all pairs 0 - 1999, subset the two rows, remove any columns with nonzero columns, then compute, but this seems horribly inefficient as it requires a ton of splices to be done.

The desired output is a matrix of 2000 x 2000 with the Jaccard index. A bonus would be to make a 4 column array intermediate, with the index of observation 1, index of observation 2, intersection, and union.

Thanks!
Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise, it should count towards the union as long as at least one of the entries is nonzero.

No matter what, you will have to make O(n^2) comparisons. In particular, there are n(n-1)/2 possible pairs. So any speedups will come from the comparisons themselves.

It seems like the value of the entries does not matter for your definition, so things will be faster if you cast to booleans. Suppose `X=my_sparse_array.astype('bool)'` is your sparse boolean array of size (2000,10000000). You can compute the intersection and union between rows `i` and `j` as:

```
intersection = scipy.sum(X[i].multiply(X[j]))
union = scipy.sum(X[i]+X[j])
```

The multiply function acts pointwise, so the `k`-th entry of `X[i].multiply(X[j])` is 1 if both the `k`-th entries of `X[i]` and `X[j]` are one, and zero otherwise. Therefore it acts as the logical and operation. Likewise, `+` acts as the logical or operation. Sum simply gives the number of nonzero entries in a row.